# The value show in the multi-select function not properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select, bootstrap-multiselect

I have 2 problems in the multi-select function:

i)The first problem, I set the value if clicked the `Show Volvo and Opel` and `Show Volvo and Saav` buttons, will follow the value shown in the multi-select box. Now the error is if clicked the `Show Volvo and Opel` button, it can show the correct values, but if clicked the `Show Volvo and Saav` button, the value cannot show properly.

ii)The second problem, if I clicked the `Show Volvo and Opel`, it just can show the `checked` value in the multi-select box, the value of name cannot show in the multi-select box, for example, I need to show name `Volvo, Opel` like below this picture:

[image: output]

Below is my sample working coding:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cars').multiselect({
      nonSelectedText: 'Choose the car',
      enableFiltering: true,
      enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
      buttonWidth:'100%'
     });
    });
  
  

function sendFunc(){
$(this).prop('checked',false);
  var cars = [];
  var cars = ["volvo", "opel"];

for(var i = 0; i < cars.length;i++) {
    $(':checkbox[value="'+cars[i]+'"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
  }
  
function sendFunc_2(){
$(this).prop('checked',false);
  var cars = [];
  var cars = ["volvo", "saab"];

for(var i = 0; i < cars.length;i++) {
    $(':checkbox[value="'+cars[i]+'"]').prop('checked', 'checked');
}
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>  
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

<select id="cars" value="" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary create-permission" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="sendFunc()">Show Volvo and Opel</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary create-permission" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="sendFunc_2()">Show Volvo and Saav</button>
```

Hope someone can guide me on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate through options inside your select-box and where `value` matches set `prop('selected', true);` and then use `$('#cars').multiselect('refresh')` to refresh your mutliselect .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cars').multiselect({
    nonSelectedText: 'Choose the car',
    enableFiltering: true,
    enableCaseInsensitiveFiltering: true,
    buttonWidth: '100%'
  });
});



function sendFunc() {
  call_to_deleselect();
  var cars = ["volvo", "opel"];
  call_to_set_Selected(cars)
}

function sendFunc_2() {
  call_to_deleselect();
  var cars = ["volvo", "saab"];
  call_to_set_Selected(cars)
}

function call_to_deleselect() {
  //remove all selected
  $('option', $('#cars')).each(function(element) {
    $(this).removeAttr('selected').prop('selected', false);
  });
}

function call_to_set_Selected(cars) {
  for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
    //add option selected
    $('option[value="' + cars[i] + '"]', $('#cars')).prop('selected', true);
  }
  //or use  $('#cars').multiselect('select',cars);
  //refresh mutlislect
  $('#cars').multiselect('refresh');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-3-typeahead/4.0.2/bootstrap3-typeahead.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-multiselect/0.9.13/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" />

<select id="cars" value="" multiple>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="opel">Opel</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br><br><br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary create-permission" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="sendFunc()">Show Volvo and Opel</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary create-permission" id="btn_save" value="Save" onclick="sendFunc_2()">Show Volvo and Saav</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answering, but I test your code on my side cannot work.

Comment: what doesn't work ? Also , are there any error inside console ?

Comment: I think I know what happens. Your answer is correct.Thanks

Comment: Can you help me on this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67380084/multiselect-selected-text-cannot-get-properly-value
Thanks.